# WPF playing a video, shopping up, can I preload?

Tags: wpf, video

Im showing a video int my application, but its being chopped up, its locally on disc so I dont understand why this is so... any way i can start to preload it before playing it - so the content would be buffered?

**EDIT:** Im playing a wmv HD video from the samples provided by Microsoft. I play the video using a MediaElement:

```
MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
        mediaElement.Source = new Uri(fileLocation, UriKind.Absolute);
        mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
```

The "chopped up behaviour refrs to that I see 2 secs, then it stops for a split second and plays again for a couple of seconds - almost like it cant read the movie fast enough to play it

**EDIT 2** Seemed to be fixed when run it on another machine guess the bottle neck is on my machine. Closing question

Comment: "chopped up" isn't very specific, and you don't say what you are using to play the video.  A snippet of xaml and a description of the precise behavior you are getting might help.  Also:  Does the same issue occur when you play the video with Windows Media Player?  What is the bit rate on the video, and how big is it?  Different techniques would be appropraite depending on these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing, see my last update